# Datagridview combobox column's value

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview combo box with a few values in there. I am trying to capture what user clicked. I tried `CellValueChanged`, `CellContentClicked` etc. but nothing works.

I want to store this value to a variable (important) and then shift the cursor to column after user has selected value.

Please help. Please also advise what event to fire.

Thanks

```
Private Sub dg_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg.CellValueChanged
    If flgLD = 1 Then
        Dim retreivedValue As Object = dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
        dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value = retreivedValue
        dg.CurrentCell = dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1)
        dg.BeginEdit(True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to capture combox value changing in datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Use CellValueChanged Event, then check what Column is chosen by the user, then you can retreive the value. Here an example:

```
Private Sub yourGrid_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles yourGrid.CellValueChanged
    If e.ColumnIndex = yourComboColumn.Index Then
        Dim retreivedValue As Object = yourGrid(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works partially, it stores value in the variable but when I added statement to change coloumnindex, it did not do that.   dg.CurrentCell = dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1)
            dg.BeginEdit(True)

Comment: Sorry, but i need more info. Where do you put that code? Inside CellValueChanged event? Can you post more code please?

Comment: Private Sub dg_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg.CellValueChanged
        If flgLD = 1 Then
            Dim retreivedValue As Object = dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
            dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value = retreivedValue
            dg.CurrentCell = dg.Rows(dg.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1)
            dg.BeginEdit(True)
        End If
    End Sub